# Retrieving column values of a csv file and processing

Tags: r

Hi I want to know how we can process the column values of a csv file.
I have a csv file which has mean and standard deviation(SD) 2 columns. I want to check whether the SD is in the range, then i want add a new column to the csv file and say SD is in the range, out of range.

data<-read.csv("file.csv") # this has parameter,value1,value2 columns

print(data) #will give the data in the file

```
parameter     value1  value2
cpu utilize    0.674    0.34
throughput     1.321    0.56
.........
```

Now i want add one more column and mention 1(value1 is between 0 & 1), else 0. I have a very long file containing different parameters

Comment: Welcome to SO! being your first question, go through other questions and check how to incorporate the code, how to add a reproducible data example and so on. Take your time and then re-edit. This would just be an initial struggle!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with logical operators, subsetting and assignment:

```
# Make dummy data
df = data.frame(parameter=c("grapes", "plums", "bananas", "apples"), value1=rnorm(16, mean=1), value2=rnorm(16))

# Add range check
df$zero2one = 0
df$zero2one[df$value1 > 0 & df$value1 < 1] = 1

# Summarise
summary(df)
```